# Sharing dynamic between frontend head and body

Tags: reflex, reflex-dom

New to haskell, but I'm not sure that you can create a dynamic that can go into both head and body. I'd like to update page title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTitle`](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-dom/blob/b8e483adef0cea66d081c1a014e87c6f99eb29fc/ghcjs-dom-jsffi/src/GHCJS/DOM/JSFFI/Generated/Document.hs#L1261) to accomplish this.